# Basic question on rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have some commutative ring $R$ with unity
and two ideals $I \subseteq J.$
Is there a natural way to view $R/J $
as a subring of $R/I$ (or some sort of map to see this)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R=\mathbb Z$, $I=(0)$ and $J=2\mathbb Z$.

Is $R/J$ a subring of $R/I$ in any way?

Comment: hmmm. I guess not. Thanks!